# How to deploy webService and get access to wsdl?

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, jax-ws

I have got a webService without ui. It simple jax-ws app that will allow to manage users via soap requests. I tried to deploy it on websphere. It was deployed, But! my app doesn't appear in Service Providers and i can't get access to wsdl file via url that i pass in `wsdlsoap:aderess location`. It haven't got any servlets and other stuff. I create my app using template that deploy with success, it appear in Service Providers. I research all internet, but idk what go wrong.

P.S: Template project was eclipse project. I just add maven and has no idea why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your web service hasn't appeared in the Service Providers section means you've deployed it the wrong way.

1. Check whether you've selected the "Deploy web-services" option during deployment.
2. You probably got an issue in your trace.log file which possibly references to the ffdc, check it to investigate the problem.
3. You also haven't mentioned if you using servlet or EJB-based web services.

Comment: шf i try to enable "Deploy web-services" it doesn't deploy

Comment: Then go to the next step and try to investigate it through logs. It usually flows into some ffdc problem.
Are you using EJB or servlet?

Comment: we use ejb in out project

Comment: while installing i got error wsws0038e deployment error java.io.IOException The system cannot find the path scpecified

Comment: How did you create the classes? As it comes from the description you have a WSDL file? Top-down or bottom-up? It would probably a good idea to share some code and deployment descriptors. Do you have a full stack trace or whatever related this issue?

Comment: yes, it will, but the project that i try to deploy based in private network that didn't have connect with www. It hard to rewrite it. top-down or bottom-up... it hard to check it. Guy that write it before me leave the project 6 month ago. I ask him, but hi didn't remember

Comment: as i understand it was bottom-up

Comment: You should shed some light onto the mentioned wsws0038e deployment error. If you're investigating your trace.log file, then such issue is usually followed by some detailed info related to that. Check it more thoroughly. What I see at the moment is a total lack of information.